# google cloud storage service account access not configured

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on a PHP script that automatically uploads PDF documents to a Google cloud 
bucket.

I'm using Google's cloud storage service account.

The result I'm getting is:
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta1/b/..: (403) Access Not Configured

The PHP code that I'm using (the php google api client lib)  is as follows:

```
$clientID = 'MY CLIENT ID';
$keyFile = 'PATH\TO\KEYFILE\key.p12';
$key_secret = 'MY KEY SECRET';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientID);
$client->setApplicationName("Google Cloud Storage Sample");
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control');

$key = file_get_contents($keyFile);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    'service account name',
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'),
    $key,$key_secret)
);

$storageService = new Google_StorageService($client);
try 
{
   $bucket = $storageService->buckets->get('my_bucket');


}      
catch (exception $e)
{
    print $e->getMessage();
}


Thanks for any support on this one.
```

Comment: Did u manage to make this work ? I m just starting to learn this and it seems that there is not a lot of working samples for PHP.

Comment: Make sure Google Cloud Storage JSON API enabled in your API Console

Comment: Mine is enabled but still getting the same error. It's not php related, because I'm making pure HTTP requests before putting it in production. They say we have to "wait some minutes before the change propagate through their system". But it's taking hours already, not minutes.